# Obfuscate Python Script with PyArmor

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyarmor

I am trying to obfuscate a Python script with PyArmor (https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
As explained in the Docs, I ran the obfuscation command `pyarmor obfuscate myscript.py` and everything is fine, but then there comes up a problem when I try to distribute the code.

The issue is when I try to distribute the obfuscated script. Due to they key.lic the Obfuscator creates, I can not distribute the script, as the key is bound to the machine where it was created.

So my question is, how could I just obfuscate the scripts, without binding them to any machine? It would be really nice if anyone could help me out with this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Any Updates on this? If this is still an issue, that really defeats the purpose of pyarmor, which is to be able to obfuscate the script from ANYONE.

Comment: You need to distribute the `dist` folder, not just the script for it to work.